# What is the cabinet covering a range hood called?

Tags: kitchens, cabinets

What's the name of this curved cabinet overhang / mask? I can't figure it out.
I assume it's to hide the unfinished side of the upper wall cabinet, and I need one, but I don't know what to look for.

[image: What's it called]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an **arched valance** with a mantel hood above it. For example:

http://www.castlewood.com/avmantelhood.html

Answer (score 1):

That is a stove exhaust hood. Notice that it's above a stove top. Also notice the extension above the cabinet; this hides the the tubing loading to a roof vent.

Comment: right, I'm looking for the name of the cabinet extension - or is it just called cabinet extension ?

Comment: @Matt Just to clarify: you're asking about the part above the cabinets? This is confusing since you drew an arrow pointing at the hood.